# Why is this Volley jsonObjectRequest not working properly in AppWidgetProvider()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am successfully calling for and receiving json data... I am not getting any errors... Logcat is displaying the proper information... I can hard code setTextViewsText outside of the request... But, my city TextView is not changing in this block of code!

I've been struggling with this for two days and I've tried everything I can think of and everyting I could find on stackoverflow. I am relatively new to Kotlin and Android, so please be gentle. ;)

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

views.setTextViewText(R.id.city, "Some City") // this works

val jsonObjectRequest = 
JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    { response ->
        try {
            val yourCity = response.getString("name")
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.city, yourCity) // this doesn't work
            Log.i("city", "Your City: $yourCity ")
       } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
       }
    }
) { }

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
```

Logcat displays:

```
I/city: Your City: Mountain View
```

Manifest includes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing good, but you have to call `updateAppWidget()` after `views.setTextViewText(R.id.city, yourCity)`, to update the view on user's screen.

Comment: OMG! It worked! Thank you so much for your help! I called for the update outside of the JsonObjectRequest and I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to figure this out. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Sandy you should accept the answer if it worked for you.